# CakePHP - Using localization function (__()) into core files

Tags: cakephp, localization, cakephp-2.0

I have this into my Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Product', array(
    ...
    'Colors' => array(
        'black'     => __('Black'), 
        'brown'     => __('Brown'), 
        'grey'      => __('Grey'), 
        'white'     => __('White'), 
        'blue'      => __('Blue')
    ),
    ...
));
```

In a view file (.ctp), I'm rendering that array as a JSON:

```
$config = array(
   ...
   'colors' => Configure::read('Product.Colors'),
   ...
);

echo '(function(){window.AppCfg=' . json_encode($config) . '}).call(this);';
```

If now I change the current language, the colors remains in English. If I paste the array from core.php straight into my .ctp, then it works fine - Why? I'm sure I have used __() into core.php before.

Comment: And where, when and how exactly are you changing the language?

Comment: It's hardcoded at the beginning of core.php: `Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to early to do this in `core.php`, by [the time this file is included](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php#L75), the proper paths for the app [aren't built yet](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php#L80), and consequently binding the textdomain will fail as [the locale path is yet unknown](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php#L273).

Just move everything that involves calling `__()` (this is what triggers the textdomain binding) from your `core.php` into your `bootstrap.php` file and you should be good.

Comment: Tried putting `Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');` into bootstrap and AppController->beforeFilter, but nothing.

Comment: If I redeclare `Configure::write('Product.Colors', ...)` into `AppController->beforeFilter()` then it works, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Maybe I should have made that a little more clear, it's the `Configure::write('Product', ...)` part that must go into the `bootstap.php` file, ie the calls to `__()` as they are actually causing the textdomain binding to be triggered. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I added `Configure::write('Product.Colors', ...)` into `bootstrap.php` and tried leaving `Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');` in `core.php` and/or `AppController->beforeFind()`

Comment: It works fine for me, try cleaning your app cache. And note that `Configure::write('Config.language', ..)` must be invoked _before_ using `__()`, so it should work in `core.php`, but definitely not in `AppController::beforeFind()`.

Comment: You said I have to put Product.Colors in bootstrap and leave Config.language in core, but call Config.language before invoking __()... isn't bootstrap loaded/executed before core?

Comment: No, `bootstrap.php` is included after `core.php`, if it where the other way around, then my answer wouldn't make any sense at all ;) Also note that you don't have to leave the `Config.language` part in `core.php`, you could move that into `bootstrap.php` too, however it should also work when leaving it in `core.php`.

Comment: Now everything is clear, working and making sense again ;) - Thanks!